# React native reanimated useAnimatedStyle keep spitting me the error

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm trying to implement some fade-in and out transition for icons with react native reanimated. The version of it is 2.1.0. I'm using the bare workflow of expo. And the code looks like this

```
...
const IconWrapper: React.FC<IconWrapperProps> = ({
  wrapperStyle,
  children
}) => {

  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState<number>(0);
  const animatedOpacity = useSharedValue(opacity);
    
  const hookUpdater = () => {
    return {
      opacity: withTiming(animatedOpacity.value , {
        duration: 100,
        easing: Easing.linear
      })
    };
  };

  const animationStyle = useAnimatedStyle(hookUpdater, [opacity]);

  const hookEffect = () => {
    setOpacity(1);
    const cleaner = () => setOpacity(0);
    return cleaner;
  };
  
  useEffect(hookEffect, []);

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={[wrapperStyle, animationStyle]}
    >
      {children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default IconWrapper;
```

For me, it seems that there is no problem, since I actually did the same thing which is in the documentation. But it keeps spitting me the error like

```
TypeError: Object.values requires that input parameter not be null or undefined
```

I've tried resetting cache with `expo start -c`, but it didn't work. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are making a different functions hookUpdater and hookEffect but not passing those inside the dependency list in animationStyle and useEffect since those are also dependencies. So adding those will work.

```
  const animationStyle = useAnimatedStyle(hookUpdater, [hookUpdater]);
  ...
  useEffect(hookEffect, [hookEffect]);
```

And better make the hookUpdater and hookEffect use useCallback as well.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response! It'll help me a lot in the future!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know why, but the updater passed into useAnimatedStyle hook should be anonymous function. So this part should be look like

```
  const animationStyle = useAnimatedStyle(
    () => {
      return {
        opacity: withTiming(animatedOpacity.value, {
          duration: 100,
          easing: Easing.linear
        })
      };
    },
    [opacity]
  );
```

Hope this can be helped for someone who struggling with this same problem.